# Nib objects (subviews) accessing properties in ViewController

Tags: iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch

Edited for brevity:

**How does a subview access properties in its superview and its superview's view controller?** Easy enough to go down the chain. How do we go back up?

Original (verbose) post:

The immediate problem I'm trying to solve is simplifying the "birth" of a somewhat complex view. The large picture has to do with Nibs and how subclasses (of UIView in particular) that have beyond trivial initializers are  reconstituted when the view loads.

I have some custom UIViews - subviews of a subview of my viewcontroller's view. When I instantiate these views in particular they need a reference to some properties (NSNumberFormatter, & NSDictionary) of the View Controller.

Currenty I use a method to instantiate them:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame items:(NSDictionary *)dictionary forEditingMode:(EditingMode)mode
```

I'm experimenting with moving them into a Nib to let them reconstitute themselves and running into basic design issues. One being I think I'm limited to initWithFrame as the default initializer?!?  If so how can these objects look into the parent view controller and get a reference to the dictionary and some other properties?

Are there methods I could call within initWithFrame (similar to the ones that retrieve the UIApplication delegate) but would instead allow the child view to send methods to it's parent views and/or controllers?

Send in the MVC police, I'm sure I'm breaking something...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set up outlets that get connected to the view's superview or view controller and pull out the info in `awakeFromNib`.  You need to use `awakeFromNib` instead of `init*` because the connections won't be created until then.

FYI, if you instantiate via a Nib, your designated initializer is `initWithCoder:`, not `initWithFrame:` (but don't use either for this).

Comment: so you're saying put an IBOutlet in these subviews that points back to the superview or viewcontroller? i haven't come across that before...is it fairly common?

Comment: It's essentially the delegate pattern. You give the subview an outlet named `delegate`, and a delegate protocol (historically, this would be informal, although now you can use a formal protocol with optional methods). Then you make the superview conform to the protocol. Finally, you set it as the delegate, either in IB or with an accessor message.

Comment: Yup, like Peter said, your view controller essentially becomes a delegate for the subview.  Make sure you make this an `assign` property or you'll end up with a retain cycle.

Answer (score 1):

It should work the other way round.

The views only contain controls (text fields, etc.). The data lives in a *model*, and the view/window controllers mediate, accessing and setting the view controls values, synchronizing with the model.

OK, sometimes you may need to have a dictionary shared between the controller and the view. Then create a dictionary property in the view and set it in the awakeFromNib method of the nib owner.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably be doing this through the view controller manually just after the nib is loaded. This means that you will have to set the shared dictionary **AFTER** the view has been initialized. You might do it like so:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet MyView* view1;
    IBOutlet MyView* view2;
    IBOutlet MyView* view3;
}
@end

@implementation MyViewController

-(void) viewDidLoad;
{
    NSDictionary* sharedDict = //make the shared dictionary here;
    view1.sharedDict = sharedDict;
    view2.sharedDict = sharedDict;
    view3.sharedDict = sharedDict;
}

@end
```